# Understand subnet ranges from nmap output

Tags: networking, subnet, nmap

I'm trying to find the subnet-ranges in a big network, this are my passages:
I use nmap to discover alive hosts and to make a traceroute toward all of them.
After that I can draw the network topology using the traceroute info, but I can't associate every host Ip with the subnet it belongs to, because nmap can't supply this info.

This is nmap's output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///usr/local/share/nmap/nmap.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<!-- Nmap 6.25 scan initiated Thu Jan 17 14:48:44 2013 as: /usr/local/bin/nmap -&#45;datadir /usr/local/share/nmap -oX - -sn -&#45;traceroute -f -&#45;badsum -T4 aa.bb.*.1-10 -->
<nmaprun scanner="nmap" args="/usr/local/bin/nmap -&#45;datadir /usr/local/share/nmap -oX - -sn -&#45;traceroute -f -&#45;badsum -T4 aa.bb.*.1-10" start="1358430524" startstr="Thu Jan 17 14:48:44 2013" version="6.25" xmloutputversion="1.04">
<verbose level="0"/>
<debugging level="0"/>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.5.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.254.13" rtt="435.69"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.5.5" rtt="6.54"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="8786" rttvar="6087" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.5.6" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.254.13" rtt="435.69"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.5.6" rtt="7.65"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="9876" rttvar="7052" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430540"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.16.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.16.5" rtt="15.74"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="61488" rttvar="76772" to="368576"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.16.8" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.16.8" rtt="16.64"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="18283" rttvar="14326" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.16.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.16.9" rtt="19.44"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="53411" rttvar="63923" to="309103"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.16.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.16.10" rtt="19.94"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="54037" rttvar="63398" to="307629"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.17.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.17.5" rtt="25.50"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="53848" rttvar="62222" to="302736"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.18.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.18.5" rtt="27.33"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="54679" rttvar="61420" to="300359"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.18.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.18.10" rtt="27.34"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="60353" rttvar="71855" to="347773"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.19.6" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.138" rtt="27.07"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.19.6" rtt="27.33"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="63600" rttvar="75779" to="366716"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430536"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.32.8" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.32.8" rtt="59.18"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="13005" rttvar="18000" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430536"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.32.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.32.9" rtt="59.17"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="12991" rttvar="17989" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430536"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.33.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.33.5" rtt="59.15"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="23099" rttvar="23762" to="118147"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.33.8" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.33.8" rtt="59.21"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="9802" rttvar="17866" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430536"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.33.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.33.9" rtt="59.21"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="23098" rttvar="23772" to="118186"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430540"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.33.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.33.10" rtt="3.55"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="6560" rttvar="6102" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="61"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.34.5" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.34.5" rtt="5.25"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="4278" rttvar="4028" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430527"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.34.8" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.129" rtt="11.90"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.34.8" rtt="5.26"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="2360" rttvar="4577" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430528"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.65.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.13" rtt="12.02"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.65.9" rtt="7.78"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="11350" rttvar="9916" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430528"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.65.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.13" rtt="12.02"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.65.10" rtt="7.77"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="17875" rttvar="17375" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430528"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.66.8" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.13" rtt="12.02"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.66.8" rtt="7.76"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="15675" rttvar="14863" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430528"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.66.9" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.13" rtt="12.02"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.66.9" rtt="7.77"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="18615" rttvar="18222" to="100000"/>
</host>
<host starttime="1358430524" endtime="1358430528"><status state="up" reason="echo-reply" reason_ttl="125"/>
<address addr="aa.bb.66.10" addrtype="ipv4"/>
<hostnames>
</hostnames>
<trace proto="icmp">
<hop ttl="1" ipaddr="aa.bb.190.1" rtt="11.64"/>
<hop ttl="2" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.5" rtt="5.03"/>
<hop ttl="3" ipaddr="aa.bb.252.13" rtt="12.02"/>
<hop ttl="4" ipaddr="aa.bb.66.10" rtt="8.98"/>
</trace>
<times srtt="19534" rttvar="18794" to="100000"/>
</host>
<runstats><finished time="1358430750" timestr="Thu Jan 17 14:52:30 2013" elapsed="226.36" summary="Nmap done at Thu Jan 17 14:52:30 2013; 2560 IP addresses (295 hosts up) scanned in 226.36 seconds" exit="success"/><hosts up="295" down="2265" total="2560"/>
</runstats>
</nmaprun>
```

I have some questions:

1. I can't find options or scripts for nmap that can help me with this. Do you know any of these that can help me?
2. If I have  3 addresses like aa.bb.252.5, aa.bb.252.13 and aa.bb.252.138 can I say that these addresses belongs to the same network if they finish with .252.x?
3. If I have aa.bb.16.5, aa.bb.16.9, aa.bb.16.10, aa.bb.17.5, aa.bb.18.5, aa.bb.18.10, aa.bb.19.16 these addresses can belong to the same subnet?
4. If aa.bb. is equal to 145.132. can I say that the subnet-mask is 255.255.0.0?
5. Suppose that (1) every address starts with 149.132, (2) that the host that performs the scan is in the same subnet of 149.132.190.1 with mask 255.255.255.0 and (3) that route hops are: 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> .16.5 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> 16.8 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> 252.138 --> 16.9 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> .17.5
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> .18.5 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> 18.10 
   .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> 19.6 
   With this topology, how can I understand if a node (for example 149.132.16.5) belongs to the same subnet of another one (for example 149.132.18.10)? Can I understand the subnet-mask or the subnet-range reasoning over the traceroute hops?

Thank you all!

Leonardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When hosts communicate over the network, they communicate using their IP addresses, and seldom communicate their subnet masks. If you have access to the actual routers/switches, you will be able to retrieve the subnet information, but if not, I am currently unable to think of a way other than connecting to each host via SSH and running ifconfig.
2. No. You cannot assume based on the IP addresses that the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. Although this will be a good guess.
3. Yes, they can all belong to the same subnet. e.g. the subnet mask of 255.255.0.0 will do it. However, as I answered in number 2 above, you cannot assume this.
4. No, see 2 and 3 above.
5. Basically, it is not possible to retrieve the subnet information with 100% certainty using the information given by trace route. However, you can make a good guess as to what they would be, and you are probably going to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

All of your addresses have a network address. If you mask the address with your subnet mask, you'll get the network address.

=> Same network address, same network (subnet).

Steps to do (for learning maybe):

- write down address (binary).
- write down subnet mask (binary and directly under the address)
- make a third row and fill with "0" unnless address AND subnet mask have "1" on this position, then write down "1".

now you have the network address. Do this for 2 addresses and if the come out having the same network address, they both are in the same subnet.

```
192.168.  0.1   => 1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0001
255.255.255.0   => 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 0000 0000
network address => 1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 => 192.168.0.0

192.168.  0.2   => 1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0010
255.255.255.0   => 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 1111 1111 . 0000 0000
network address => 1100 0000 . 1010 1000 . 0000 0000 . 0000 0000 => 192.168.0.0
```

so 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2 are in the same subnet (called 192.168.0.0).

So on (2) No. The subnet mask could split 252.x in 2 subnets (252.0-127 and 252.128 - 255 maybe).
(3) Yes. If the subnet mask only splits on aa.bb-level
(4) No. Same reason as (2) but backwards.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I didn't explained well. Suppose that (1) every address starts with 149.132, (2) that the host that performs the scan is in the same subnet of 149.132.190.1 with mask 255.255.255.0 and (3) that route hops are:                             .190.1 --> .252.5 --> .252.138 --> .16.5 # .252.138 --> 16.8 # 252.138 --> 16.9 # .252.138 --> .17.5# .252.138 --> .18.5 # .252.138 --> 18.10 # .252.138 --> 19.6 #  With this topology, how can I understand if a node belongs to the same subnet of another one? Can I reason on the hops without knowing the mask of every address?

Comment: *IF* the subnet mask *is* 255.255.255.0 you can assume that they are *not* in the same subnet. If it would be 255.255.0.0 then they would be all in the same subnet. For 255.255.255.0 you would have subnets called a.b.190.0 and a.b.252.0 and .16.0 .17.0 .18.0 and .19.0

Comment: So, if I know that my pc with mask 255.255.255.0 is in subnet 190.x, i can say that all the other subnets are .number.x?

Comment: if they use the same mask, yes. See my example and change numbers on third block. 255 basically means everything is "different" (different subets) and 0 means "all the same".